# a Unhandled exception :Access violation reading location 0x00000004

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I get this error in the debugging mode when i first encounter the marked line in the code below

```
#include<fstream>
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{int t,i,j,k,n,g[100],w[100],opp[100];
float rpi[100],wp[100],owp[100],oowp[100];
char s[100][100];
ifstream ip; ip.open("A-small-practice.in"); ofstream op; op.open("A_out.in");
ip>>t; 
for(i=0;i<t;i++)
  { ip>>n;
    memset(g,0,sizeof(g));
    memset(w,0,sizeof(w));
    memset(op,0,sizeof(op));
    memset(rpi,0,sizeof(rpi));
    memset(wp,0,sizeof(wp)); 
    memset(owp,0,sizeof(owp));
    memset(oowp,0,sizeof(oowp));
    memset(s,'.',sizeof(s));

    for(j=0;j<n;j++)
      {for(k=0;k<n;k++)
        {ip>>s[j][k]; //<--------------------the error occurs here
        if(s[j][k]=='0')
          g[j]++;
    if(s[j][k]=='1')
      {g[j]++;w[j]++;}
        }
      wp[j]=w[j]/g[j];
     }

    for(j=0;j<n;j++)
      {for(k=0;k<n;k++)
       if(j!=k && s[k][j]!='.')
           {owp[j]+=(wp[k]*g[k]-s[k][j])/(g[k]-1);
           opp[j]++;
           }
       owp[j]/=opp[j];
      } 

    for(j=0;j<n;j++)
      {for(k=0;k<n;k++)
        {if(j!=k && s[k][j]!='.')
         oowp[j]+=owp[k];
        }
       oowp[j]/=opp[j]; 
      }

   op<<"Case #"<<i+1<<": \n"; 
    for(j=0;j<n;j++)
    {rpi[j]=(0.25*wp[j]) + (0.5*owp[j]) +(0.25*oowp[j]);
    op<<rpi[j]<<"\n";
     } 
 } 
return 0; 
}
```

the debugger breaks at this code segment when stepped in. The loops and logic the value size is all correct i don't know where the overflow is ocurring..is there any other cause for this?

```
    class _Sentry_base
    {   // stores thread lock and reference to input stream
public:
    __CLR_OR_THIS_CALL _Sentry_base(_Myt& _Istr)
        : _Myistr(_Istr)
        {   // lock the stream buffer, if there
        if (_Myistr.rdbuf() != 0)//<-------------break points here
            _Myistr.rdbuf()->_Lock();
        }
```

Comment: What's the value of `n` at that point?

Comment: the values are well within range...here it is 3 when first executed

Comment: @aseem dua, can you try declaring the arrays in global scope and run the program to see if it still crashes?

Comment: @ Donotalo unfortunetely, yes it still does :( i have even removed memset(s, '.' sizeof(s))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `memset` for the 1D arrays.  For example

```
 int g[100] = {0};
```

will work.

For the 2D array, loop through using a for loop and set each element to `'.'`, or stick with the `memset` for that step.

In terms of your actual problem, you may need to use `ip.get()` to read character by character instead.

Comment: `memset(s,'.',sizeof(s));` will do the same.

Comment: @Donotalo Thanks, I couldn't remember if the 2D array would work.  For the 1D arrays, I think it's more effective to remember to do it when you declare them.

Comment: it will work of nD array as long as the array is statically allocated. :)